# Facebook sdk: ActiveSession is still closed after I give permission

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating facebook login in my application. I jsut want the user to be able to login and I get his birthday and Location.

I got the latest Facebook SDK and successfully added it to my application. I also created a new application on facebook and added the key provided to my application.

I have created a button "Login with facebook" and done the following

When the user clicks the button

```
// handler for button click
- (IBAction)facebookLoginTouched:(id)sender {
    [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}
```

This method will show the user the facebook login page in order to get his permission

```
-(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_location",
                            @"user_birthday",
                            nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self HandleLogin];
                                     }];
}
```

Then if login and permission successful

```
- (void)HandleLogin {
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        //THIS IS NEVER REACHED

        [FBRequestConnection
         startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                       id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                       NSError *error) {
             //DO SOMETHING WITH THE USER INFO
         }];
    }
}
```

**My problem:**

When I click on the button the facebook page comes in correctly and I enter my username/password. It logged me correctly and I gave permission for the application to access my information. When I finish, I return to the app successfully.

However when the code reaches `FBSession.activeSession.isOpen` it returns false.

Why is the session still closed after I correctly logged in and gave permission?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be missing code to process the return from the Facebook app. Add the following in your app delegate implementation file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
   return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```